# How to fix "not a valid win32 aplication" when using JNI

Tags: java, c++, qt, java-native-interface

I am trying to use a C++ code written using Qt components(not gui related) in Java. However When I export it to a dll and call it from java I get "not a valid win32 application" error.

I compile the C++ side on QtCreator since it has Qt dependencies.

Then I put the resulting dll in one of the library paths of java(System32 right now, for testing)

Then I put the java code I used to create the native code in a .jar file and include it in another project.

I would like to call the functions from that project.

Here is the contests of my Qt .pro file

```
QT += widgets network
QT -= gui
TARGET = JNIOpenSdkWrapper
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += create_prl

DEFINES += JNIOPENSDKWRAPPER_LIBRARY
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

#... headers and source files here ...

INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_211/include"
INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_211/include/win32"

unix{
    target.path = /usr/lib
    INSTALLS += target
}
```

When I run that project I get UnsatisfiedLinkError saying "%1 is not a valid Win32 application".

Edit: I am using MinGW 64 bit compiler and java 1.8

Comment: Are you using a 32- or 64-bit jvm?

Comment: 64bit jvm is what i am using

Comment: Use [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to debug such issues. Very probably it cannot locate the Qt DLLs.